# python - datetime x plot distortion problem

Tags: python, datetime, plot

[image]

It is a graph using datetime, but if use axhline, the graph looks very distorted. Why is that?

The form of the source is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


csv =  pd.read_csv('e:/ktskt.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
csv['date'] = csv['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
csv.set_index(csv['date'], inplace=True)

print(csv)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='r', linewidth=1)

plt.plot(csv['KT'], linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()
```